# Navigation through the SegmentedControll (AutoLayout)

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

Good day!

How to arrange elements in ViewController so that when you switch SegmentedControll changed the contents of the second bottom half?

How to implement this with autolayout?

Thank you!

Ps. Very similar interface with Instagram (the first and second tabs). The Android turned out using TabHost, and there really tight... Or maybe this differently implemented and easier?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Segmented Control?

Comment: Oops, changed the text

Comment: can't you simply hide-show the views with an animation ? what do you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `UISegmentedControl`, you will have to manually manage switching the view controllers yourself.

You should take a look at these github projects, they provide view controller management coupled with a `UISegmentedControl`:

[SNFSegmentedViewController](https://github.com/sethfri/SNFSegmentedViewController)

[SDCSegmentedViewController](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCSegmentedViewController)

The other option is to use a `UITabBarController` instead. If you want a different look than what is provided by the `UISegmentedControl`, using the `UITabBarController` is the better option.